# Book series in the future with a plague, artificial intelligences, and a mining planet taken over by machines

Tags: story-identification

I'm actually not sure if it was a book series, but there was a question to identify this story several months ago that linked to a website that explained the history and events that took place in this universe.

The setting was in the future in our solar system. There was a plague on Earth, "The Black Plague" I believe, that was killing plants on farms, and  it found it's way into orbital farms. There was an event where contact with either Venus or Mercury was lost and the machines on the planet took over. They started shooting at whatever ship came close, then started sending machines out into the solar system to assimilate other machinery.

I also remember a section describing artificial intelligences that are god-like. One in particular, named Gaia I believe, saved the solar system from the machines and plague. There were multiple tiers of existence, or something, with combinations of biological and artificial entities.

I remember a section describing how people who were living around Jupiter didn't really care about what was happening to the inner planets, but the machines that were attacking eventually reached them and it was bad.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204242/website-with-a-collection-of-sci-fi-stories-set-in-the-same-universe-powerful-a

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly certain you got linked to [Orion's Arm](https://orionsarm.com/eg-article/559d3b5ae17aa)

Everything matches in some form or another

"At its most basic level, the fungal life form that would come to be known as the Black Rot was purely biological, although a biology that had been artificially optimized in various ways to make the Rot both highly resilient and extremely efficient."

"the first post-evacuation expedition sent to Mercury to try to take back control of the Neumann systems, consisting of a half dozen craft carrying a small army of programmers, Neumann designers, and experts in system theory, was fired upon and nearly destroyed as it entered orbit"

"the various Jovian communities felt little reason for concern"

The GAIA AI is actually a separate link within the page

Comment: You should quote some fragments from the linked page that support this, just in case of link rot.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!